# Align Content Left of Element

Tags: css, alignment

Here's my code:

```
<ul class="items">
    <li class="product1"><a href=""><span>Televisions</span></a></li>
    <li class="product2"><a href=""><span>Networked Computer Stoarge</span></a></li>
</ul><!--end items-->
```

If you can imagine the `href` being a circular icon, I am trying to position the `<span>` content directly to the left of the icon: Televisions(icon)

My CSS:

```
#ir-content ul{list-style-type:none !important;}
#ir-content ul.items li{position:absolute;}
#ir-content ul.items li a{background:url(../images/rooms/dollar-sign-sprite.png) no-repeat 9px 10px;width:55px;height:53px;display:block;color:#636363 !important;position:relative;}
#ir-content ul.items li a:hover{background-position:0 -135px;text-decoration:none !important;}
#ir-content li a span{margin:0;padding:6px 20px 6px 0;background:url(../images/rooms/product-title-bg.png) no-repeat right top;position:relative;left:-100%;top:18px;}
```

Update: Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pKnXA/1/

Notice how I can get it almost fully to the left of the icon, but there's still some overlap.

Comment: How do you mean href="" being a circular icon?

Comment: Does anchoring the image to the right and adding some right padding to the containing `a` not work because your sprite has multiple images horizontally?

Comment: I've added a fiddle. See update note above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative/absolute positioning fiddling: http://jsfiddle.net/pKnXA/2/

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty straight forwards just have the background image positioned to the right and add padding?

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position

Comment: Thanks. But it's a bit more complicated than that. I'll try and get a fiddle up.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to add some right padding on to your `a` element, and then anchor your background image to the right side.

However, if that does not work, perhaps because you're using a sprite that has additions images horizontally, what you can do is add an additional `div` with dimensions that wrap a single image in the sprite, and float that to the right inside your `a` element.

You would then need to move your CSS for repositioning the background image on hover to affect the new `div`, instead.